# Presumably simple PHP if/else statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I seem to be having trouble with another piece of what seems to be super basic PHP, but it just won't work for me.

My client (real estate website) needs to be able to have properties with no price to be either “price upon request” OR “auction”. Currently, leaving the price field blank only allows for one.

I tried changing the following code:

```
$listing_price_labels = array(
‘sold’ => __( ‘Sold’, ‘wpsight’ ),
‘rented’ => __( ‘Rented’, ‘wpsight’ ),
‘request’ => __( ‘Price on request’, ‘wpsight’ ),
‘auction’ => __( ‘Auction’, ‘wpsight’ ), ***– Added this line***
);
```

And where this code is found…

```
if( is_admin() ) 
        $listing_price .= ‘<br />’ . wpsight_get_price_value();

    } elseif( empty( $listing_price ) ) {

        // When no price available Price on request
        $listing_price = ‘<span class=”listing-price-on-request”>’ . $listing_price_labels['request'] . ‘</span><!– .listing-price-on-request –>’;

    } elseif( $listing_price = ‘auction’ ) {

        // When price field contains ‘auction’ (case sensitive)
        $listing_price = ‘<span class=”listing-price-on-request”>’ . $listing_price_labels['auction'] . ‘</span><!– .listing-price-on-request –>’;

    }



    function wpsight_get_price( $post_id = '' ) {

        // Get post ID from $post_id

        if( empty( $post_id ) )
            $post_id = get_the_ID();    

        // If still empty, return false

        if( empty( $post_id ) )
            return false;

        // Set listing price labels

        $listing_price_labels = array(
            'sold'    => __( 'Sold', 'wpsight'  ),
            'rented'  => __( 'Rented', 'wpsight'  ),
            'request' => __( 'Price on request', 'wpsight' ),
            'auction' => __( 'Auction', 'wpsight' ),
            );

        $listing_price_labels = apply_filters( 'wpsight_get_price_labels', $listing_price_labels );

        // Get listing price
        $listing_price = wpsight_get_price_value();

        // Get custom fields

        $custom_fields          = get_post_custom( $post_id );
        $listing_status         = isset( $custom_fields['_price_status'][0] ) ? $custom_fields['_price_status'][0] : false;
        $listing_availability   = isset( $custom_fields['_price_sold_rented'][0] ) ? $custom_fields['_price_sold_rented'][0] : false;

        // Create price output

        if( ! empty( $listing_availability ) ) {

            // When listing is not available

            $sold_rented = ( $listing_status == 'sale' ) ? $listing_price_labels['sold'] : $listing_price_labels['rented'];

            // Display sold/rented bold red in admin
            $style = is_admin() ? ' style="color:red;font-weight:bold"' : false;

            $listing_price = '<span class="listing-price-sold-rented"' . $style . '>' . $sold_rented . '</span><!-- .listing-price-sold-rented -->';

            if( is_admin() ) 
                $listing_price .= '<br />' . wpsight_get_price_value();

        } elseif( empty( $listing_price ) ) {

            // When no price available Price on request
            $listing_price = '<span class="listing-price-on-request">' . $listing_price_labels['request'] . '</span><!-- .listing-price-on-request -->';

        } elseif( $listing_price == "auction" ) {

            // When price field contains 'auction' (case sensitive)
            $listing_price = '<span class="listing-price-on-request">' . $listing_price_labels['auction'] . '</span><!-- .listing-price-on-request -->';

        }

        return apply_filters( 'wpsight_listing_price', $listing_price );

    }
```

I’m sure my syntax must just be wrong, because with that code in place it makes any property with anything at all written into the price field display “auction”.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: try `$listing_price == 'auction'` instead of `$listing_price = 'auction'`. You are actually assigning the string `'auction'` to the variable `$listing_price` instead of comparing them. In this case you can also use `===` which does not return true unless value and type match on both sides. More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: can you echo the value of `$listing_price` before your if statements?

Comment: $listing_price .= ‘<br />’ . wpsight_get_price_value(); makes this a string that is being concatenated. } elseif( empty( $listing_price ) ) { would not be empty even if the method returned false because of the break point. You could use a field that says if it's sold etc... and use the if conditions on it. You can also apply conditional display logic for each entry. Are you looping through each item?

Comment: Hi, @Andre - Sorry that was my mistake, if you see the last block of code I actually had the == operator, I worked out that mistake already and corrected it but it still didn't change anything I'm afraid.

Comment: @user3587554 - Yes I believe this code is applied to the loop of each item. You response looks promising, could you possibly provide an example of the code required?

Comment: @Viscocent - I tried echoing before the if but nothing was returned.

Comment: If you call `wpsight_get_price_value()` multiple times, does it return "auction" the second time? That's the only way I can see the behaviour you describe happen with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if( is_admin() ){
    $listing_price .= ‘<br />’ . wpsight_get_price_value();

    } elseif( empty( $listing_price ) ) {

    // When no price available Price on request
    $listing_price = ‘<span class=”listing-price-on-request”>’ . $listing_price_labels['request'] . ‘</span><!– .listing-price-on-request –>’;
}
```

btw its not recommended to use `if( is_admin() )` since its only applicable on 1 line.